Is it legal to intentionally surge & destroy neighbor's electrical equipment when they steal your residential power?
A friend of mine who worked in contracting/construction told me an interesting story about how a neighbor of theirs was stealing power via a sneaky buried extension cable from their home. They thief was using it to power bitcoin mining equipment. The contractor caught wind of this and performed the following actions:

Didn't notify police or the utility company
Turned off the power in his own home
Rewired the socket that the neighbor was stealing power from to randomly switch between standard and non-standard frequencies (he said it'd switch to 86 Hz for 5 seconds and then back to 50 Hz) and occasionally cranked the voltage up to 240V (dryer/washing machine tier).
Drunkenly fist fought the thief when the thief showed up at his front door (apparently the electrical damage was so bad, the thief's physical crypto wallet - aka retirement - was permanently destroyed)

So aside from the last point, I wasn't sure if the contractor broke any laws. A quick google/chatgpt didn't tell me anything useful. My question: did my friend break any laws? Could my contractor friend be held liable for the destruction of the thief's retirement plan?
This happened a few years ago in a more conservative county in Washington State.

united-states
Two wrongs don't make a right.
This "self-defense" response was not proportionate or necessary; the stolen power line could have simply been disconnects and any money lost due to past stolen power could have been recovered in a small claims lawsuit, or a government prosecution for petty theft.
This act of retaliation probably constituted "criminal mischief" a.k.a. vandalism, although the exact names and definitions of the offense vary from state to state. Whether the value of the lost retirement account would be considered in terms of the offense committed or its gravity would be dependent upon whether this was a foreseeable harm and the definitions of the relevant offenses.

Messing with electrical equipment is illegal in Australia unless you're a licensed electrician.
australia
In Australia, it's illegal to mess with your house's electrical sockets at all unless you're a licensed electrician.
In short, if it's anything more complex than changing a light bulb, you need to get an electrician to do it for you - and in Victoria, even that briefly became illegal a few decades ago.

Since the op's story mentioned a building contractor, what if they were a licensed electrician?
